# Questions on a function $f$ holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{z_1, ..., z_M\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

**Question**. This is a long question and I'm now stuck in one of the parts and can't proceed further:

Suppose that $f$ holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{z_1, ..., z_M\}$, that $f$ has a pole of order $N_m$ at $z_m$ where $1 \leq m \leq M$, and that $\lim_{z\to \infty} f(z) = 0$.

(a) Explain why  has a Laurent series in the form
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-N_m}^\infty c_{m,n}(z-z_m)^n$$
in a punctured ball $B^{\circ}(z_m,r_m)$ for some sufficiently small positive $r_m$.

(b) Define $f_m(z):=\sum_{n=-N_m}^{-1}c_{m,n}(z-z_m)^n$. Explain why $f-f_m$ is holomprhic.

(c) Explain why $f-(f_1 + \cdots + f_M)$ is entire and vanishes at infinity.

(d) Explain why $f = f_1 + \cdots + f_M$.

(e) Find a formula for the coefficient $c_m,n$ similar to the formula for the residue of a function at a pole of order $N$.

(f) Find a holomorphic function $F$ on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{z_1, ..., z_M\}$ such that $F' = f$.

**My attempt**. 
(a) is obvious. Take $r_m$ to be the distance to $z_m$ from the closest singularity. Then $f$ is holomorphic in $B^{\circ}(z_m,r_m)$ and so has a Laurent series. The form for the Laurent Series follows directly from the fact that $z_m$ is a pole of order $N_m$.

(b) $f-f_m$ is a power series as all negative powers will be cancelled, and thus it is holomorphic in $B^{\circ}(z_m,r_m)$.

(c) Now I'm stuck on this part. I can see why it vanishes at infinity as both $f$ and $f_m$'s vanish at infinity. But I'm not sure how to show that $f-(f_1 + \cdots + f_M)$ is entire.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: (c) At every point $z\neq z_1,...,z_M$ all the $f_i$ and $f$ are holomorphic. The $f_i$ because they are rational functions in which the denominator doesn't vanish. At each $z_i$ the $f-f_i$ is holomorphic by (b) and the sum $\sum_{j\neq i}f_j$ because it is a rational function with deniminator not vanishing at $z_i$.

Comment: (d) $f-(f_1+f_2+...+f_M)$ is entire and bounded. So, it is constant. Since the limit at $\infty$ is zero then that constant is zero.

Comment: (f) is strange. If $M=1$, $z_1=0$ and $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, then there is no $F$. If there were then $\int_{S^1} f(z)dz=\int_{S^1}F'(z)dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}F'(e^{is})ie^{is}ds=F(e^{is})|_{0}^{2\pi}=0$, but $\int_{S^1}\frac{dz}{z}\neq0$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thanks for the hints!! Just to double check, for part c you mentioned that $f-f_i$ is holomorphic at $z_i$. Is it because they have a removable singularity at $z_i$ and can be extended there?

Comment: Yes, that was what they asked to prove in (b).